# EXACT Ruby equivalent of Javascript's escape() function

Tags: javascript, ruby, escaping

Consider the string: `` ` ( ? ``

Javascript's `escape()` encodes it like this:

```
escape("` ( ?")
"%60%20%28%20%3F"
```

How can I achieve the same effect in Ruby? Nothing I try works:

```
[Dev]> CGI.escape("` ( ?")
=> "%60+%28+%3F"
[Dev]> URI.encode("` ( ?")
=> "%60%20(%20?"
[Dev]> Addressable::URI.encode("` ( ?")
=> "%60%20(%20?"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ERB::Util.url_encode` will do it:

```
>> require 'erb'
=> true
>> ERB::Util.url_encode("` ( ?")
=> "%60%20%28%20%3F"
```

Comment: not an exact copy of javascript escaping -- treats colons differently

Answer (score 4):

`URI::encode` also takes a regex to match unsafe characters which need to be escaped; you can just pass a regex matching any character:

```
URI.encode("` ( ?", /./) # => "%60%20%28%20%3F"
```

By the way, from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions):

> The escape and unescape functions do not work properly for non-ASCII characters and have been deprecated. In JavaScript 1.5 and later, use encodeURI, decodeURI, encodeURIComponent, and decodeURIComponent.

Comment: Argh, but `encodeURIComponent()` doesn't encode `(` or `)`! Why is it preferable to `escape()`?

Comment: According to Mozilla, one reason is that it handles non-ASCII characters properly. But why does it matter to you? Any decent *decoding* function will be able to handle any of these results.

Comment: Because having parens in URLs breaks all kinds of things (auto-linking logic, Markdown logic, etc)

Comment: Also, your answers is overkill – I don't want to encode safe characters, and `URI.encode(" ( ?hi", /./)` # => `"%60%20%28%20%3F%68%69"`